# urllib.request.urlopen Type Error can't concat str to bytes

Tags: python, request, urllib

I'm running python 3.9 and I'm having this issue with my code:

I'm getting `TypeError: can't concat str to bytes`

Here's my code

```py
try:
   with urllib.request.urlopen(link, headers) as f:
      print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
except urllib.error.URLError as e:
   print(e.reason)
```

Any ideas on how to solve this error?

Comment: Could you show the full error message including the stacktrace to make sure of which line raises the error?

Comment: try `requests` library, it's easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

You have so many typos in there. The main one is `read` should be `read()`.

```
try:
    with urllib.request.urlopen(link) as response:
        data = response.read().decode('utf-8')
        print(data)
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
```

Comment: the question has `read()`